# Can't turn off webpack HMR

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Using `express` 4.14.0, `webpack` 1.14.0 w/ `babel` and presets. This is my boilerplate `webpack` config I found somewhere:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

`bundle.js` is served by Express and my `app.js` was generated using `express-generator`:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I only include the contents of `app.js` to show that, as far as I can see, there's nothing referencing HMR.

I run `nodemon bin/www` alongside `webpack -d --watch` as usual and before I even open the page in my browser, something is making consistent requests to `/__webpack_hmr` and getting a 404. How do I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But i just changed the port and then it worked. Maybe because i have other projects running with webpack on that same port. So try just to change PORT and see if that can help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to consider providing a code example or otherwise expanding your answer to help the widest audience and encourage upvoting. ["Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)